# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quantity'

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am getting the error as shown in the question, and I can't figure out why. Even when trying other Stack Overflow methods of fixing this it doesn't work.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, style, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.style = style
        self.quantity = quantity
    
class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, style, quantity=1):
        Item.__init__(name, style, quantity,)

Bow = Weapon(name = "Bow", style = "WRanged", quantity = 1)
```

The lines affected with the error codes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Stuff\SG\Work\Inventory.py", line 33, in <module>
    Bow = Weapon(name = "Bow", style = "WRanged", quantity = 1)
  File "C:\Stuff\SG\Work\Inventory.py", line 12, in __init__
    Item.__init__(name, style, quantity,)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quantity'
```

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from running your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).  In particular, don't omit the line numbers - they're often crucial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
Item.__init__(name, style, quantity,)
```

for

```
super().__init__(name, style, quantity)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing **`self`** in the `Item._init__()`. You can either:

1. Add `self`:

   ```
    class Weapon(Item):
        def __init__(self, name, style, quantity=1):
            Item.__init__(self, name, style, quantity)
   ```
2. Use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

   ```
    class Weapon(Item):
        def __init__(self, name, style, quantity=1):
            super(Weapon, self).__init__(name, style, quantity)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Item.__init__` directly means you need to pass `self` as the first argument.  Simply doing `Item.__init__(name, style, quantity)` means it thinks that `name` is the Item instance (self) and style is the name, quantity is the style and quantity is missing.

So you can just specify `self` as the first argument:

```
Item.__init__(self,name, style, quantity)
```

Or since the `__init__` is in no way different you can just not override it at all:

```
class Weapon(Item):
     #default to using Item.__init__, no problem here
##    def __init__(self, name, style, quantity = 1):
##        Item.__init__(name, style, quantity)
```

Although this means that `quantity` is now a required argument but I don't think that will be an issue.

Or as others have already said you can use `super()` to figure out what methods it should use.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `super` for inheritance in Python (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) for more details):

```
class Weapon(Item):
     def __init__(self, name, style, quantity = 1):
         super(Weapon, self).__init__(name, style, quantity)
```

Comment: the trailing comma is not doing any harm just so you know.