# Getting TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' when trying to add parent table after child table with entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-2.0

I have two classes in my sqlite database, a parent table named `Categorie` and the child table called `Article`. I created first the child table class and addes entries. So first I had this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    titre=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    auteur=models.CharField(max_length=42)
    contenu=models.TextField(null=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        auto_now=False,
        verbose_name="Date de parution"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre
```

And after I have added parent table, and now my `models.py` looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Categorie(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom


class Article(models.Model):
    titre=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    auteur=models.CharField(max_length=42)
    contenu=models.TextField(null=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        auto_now=False,
        verbose_name="Date de parution"
    )
    categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre
```

So when I run `python manage.py makemigrations <my_app_name>`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lislis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.5.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lislis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.5.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\lislis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.5.egg\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\lislis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.5.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\lislis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.5.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\lislis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\lislis\Django\mon_site\blog\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Article(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\lislis\Django\mon_site\blog\models.py", line 16, in Article
    categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

I've seen some similar issues in stackoverflow, but it seems to not be the same problem: [__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quantity'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231476/init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-quantity)

Comment: wich version of django are you using?

Comment: So what are you confused about here? As the error clearly says, ForeignKey has a required argument, `on_delete`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Comment: I dont need the `on_delete` parameter,is it obligatory?

Comment: @jochri3 Yes, **required positional argument** means it is obligatory. Check the documentation to find out which option would best fit your needs.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `models.ForeignKey` in order to understand how to use it? Is this actually a question about the Django API, or is it a question about **how to read and understand the error message**?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You can change the property `categorie` of the class `Article` like this:

```
categorie = models.ForeignKey(
    'Categorie',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

and the error should disappear.

Eventually you might need another option for `on_delete`, check the documentation for more details:

[Arguments -- Model field reference -- Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#arguments)

As you stated in your comment, that you don't have any special requirements for `on_delete`, you could use the option `DO_NOTHING`:

```
# ...
on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
# ...
```

Comment: on_delete=models.CASCADE is the default in Django < 2

Comment: It does not work. 2023

Answer (score 51):

Since Django 2.x, `on_delete` is required.

[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

> Deprecated since version 1.9: on_delete will become a required
>   argument in Django 2.0. In older versions it defaults to CASCADE.

Answer (score 17):

Since Django 2.0 the ForeignKey field requires two positional arguments:

1. the model to map to
2. the on_delete argument

```py
categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Here are some methods can used in on_delete

1. CASCADE

Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey

2. PROTECT

Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising ProtectedError, a subclass of django.db.IntegrityError.

3. DO_NOTHING

Take no action. If your database backend enforces referential integrity, this will cause an IntegrityError unless you manually add an SQL ON DELETE constraint to the database field.

you can find more about on_delete by reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Answer (score 14):

From Django 2.0 `on_delete` is required:

> user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

It will delete the child table data if the User is deleted. For more details check the Django documentation.

Comment: Why this answer while Andrey response earlier with this information ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using foreignkey then you have to use "on_delete=models.CASCADE" as it will eliminate the complexity developed after deleting the original element from the parent table. As simple as that.

```
categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 4):

> Post Django version 1.9, `on_delete` became a required argument, i.e. from Django 2.0.

> In older versions, it defaults to CASCADE.

So, if you want to replicate the functionality that you used in earlier versions. Use the following argument.

```
categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

This will have the ***same effect as that was in earlier versions***, without specifying it explicitly.

[Official Documentation on other arguments that go with on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

Answer (score 3):

Here are available options if it helps anyone for on_delete

> CASCADE, DO_NOTHING, PROTECT, SET, SET_DEFAULT, SET_NULL

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know which option to enter the params.
Just want to keep the default value like `on_delete=None` before migration:

> on_delete=models.CASCADE

This is a code snippet in the old version:

```
if on_delete is None:
    warnings.warn(
        "on_delete will be a required arg for %s in Django 2.0. Set "
        "it to models.CASCADE on models and in existing migrations "
        "if you want to maintain the current default behavior. "
        "See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/%s/ref/models/fields/"
        "#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete" % (
            self.__class__.__name__,
            get_docs_version(),
        ),
        RemovedInDjango20Warning, 2)
    on_delete = CASCADE
```

Answer (score 2):

**"models.ForeignKey()"** and **"models.OneToOneField"** must have **"on_delete"** since **Django 2.0**. For example below:

**"models.ForeignKey()"**:

```py
categories = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**"models.OneToOneField"**:

```py
categories = models.OneToOneField('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem that resolved by adding both these two parameters to ForeignKey:
null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL

Answer (score 0):

For me the package manager was resolving `djangorestframework` to a lower version and the `authtoken` model did not have the on_delete. All of my models were good. You can run `django.apps.apps.get_models()` to get a list of all your models to see what libraries create their own models and might be the issue.

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me 
`pip install django-csvimport --upgrade`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Hi Mayank. You probably did something else to fix that error or you're using an earlier version of django.

Comment: This is solved by supplying a value for the "on_delete" argument to models.ForeignKey

Comment: You are using Django prior to version 2. Because all later releases have made ```on_delete``` a compulsion! By default in earlier versions, it was ```on_delete = models.CASCADE```