# Python:django: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Tags: django

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def _str_(self):
        return self.text
class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural= 'entries'

    def _str_(self):
        return self.text[:50]+"..."
```

**This is my code**,When i run:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations learning_logs
```

The answer is :

```
 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

why this warning ? I read the documentation too, but no help.

Comment: Please see this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026548/getting-typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-on-delete

Comment: What's unclear? Both the error message and [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#arguments) are explicit: you need to add the on_delete argument.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Thanks for documention . 
Now I solved this wranging.

My way is :

```
on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
```