# How to fix error "missing positional argument: 'on_delete'" when use django-notifications?

Tags: django, notifications, typeerror

Please help me with this:

```
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\notifications\models.py", line 170, in Notification
recipient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False, related_name='notifications')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Comment: is `Notification` class a django models?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on\_delete' when trying to add parent table after child table with entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026548/getting-typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-on-delete)

Comment: check if this monkey-patch is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50776076/django-1-to-django-2-on-delete-error/63111357#63111357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Notification` model has a `ForeignKey` relation to your user model. So a single user model instance can have multiple `Notification` instances associated with it. What `on_delete` means (what django is asking of you) is that if you delete an instance of your user model what should django do with all the associated `Notification` instances?

From `django 2.x` this argument became required.

Please read up on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) to see all the options. But a quick rundown.

If you want all associated `Notification` instances to be deleted when you delete an instance of user model, set `on_delete=models.CASCADE`.

```
recipient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False, related_name='notifications', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you want the notification to remain untouched when you delete an instance of a user model, use `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`. But in this case you will have to set `null=True` on the recipient field. The notification will remain but it will not **belong** to any user.

```
recipient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False,  related_name='notifications', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "**on_delete=models.CASCADE**" after the related_name='notifications'

For further reference see [Official Documentation | Model Field Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

Comment: `on_delete` is required, but you shouldn't assume that `models.CASCADE` is what the OP needs. Without an insight into the model is just a wild guess. Eventually `models.PROTECT` might be needed, or something else.

Comment: I agree. That's why I placed link to official Doc's.
I'll take care about the insights in future references.
Thanks for correcting.