# Is it correct to modify old migration files in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I'm trying to migrate my `Django` project from `Python 2.7/Django 1.11` to `Python 3.7/Django 2.1`.

And I'm a little bit confused with one issue.

`Django 2.1` marks as errors all `models.ForeignKey(...)` code strings in my project with:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

It is because since `Django 2.x`, `'on_delete'` method is required for `ForeignKey` fields
([Getting TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' when trying to add parent table after child table with entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026548/getting-typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-on-delete))

If you'll read this post, solution is pretty simple, you just need to add one of `'on_delete'` options, for example:
    `models.ForeignKey(...,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,)`

But `Django` complains not only about actual `'models.py'` file but also about all (!) migrations that include `"ForeignKey"` fields adding or alteration.

So my question is, is it safe to modify old migration files in `Django`? And is it what I should do in this situation?

Comment: In case it is in order to *fix* migrations to a newer Django version, yes, but do not *semantically* change the migrations, since a database might already have executed migrations, and thus if you change it semantically, then it is possible the database gets out of sync.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, that's the intended upgrade path as described in the [1.9 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.9/#foreignkey-and-onetoonefield-on-delete-argument):

> In order to increase awareness about cascading model deletion, the on_delete argument of ForeignKey and OneToOneField will be required in Django 2.0.
>
> **Update models and existing migrations to explicitly set the argument.** Since the default is models.CASCADE, add on_delete=models.CASCADE to all ForeignKey and OneToOneFields that don’t use a different option. You can also pass it as the second positional argument if you don’t care about compatibility with older versions of Django.

Answer (score 9):

To update your code to Django 2

```
(.*)models.ForeignKey\((((?!on_delete).)*)\)\)
$1models.ForeignKey($2, on_delete=models.CASCADE))

field=models.ForeignKey\((((?!on_delete).)*)\)
field=models.ForeignKey($1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

(.*)models.OneToOneField\((((?!on_delete).)*)\)\)
$1models.OneToOneField($2, on_delete=models.CASCADE))
```

You can use these 3 regexes to update your codebase with search and replace feature. Of course, step over by checking each replacement, but having a regex will save you time.

Comment: Saved a lot of time. Thanks. @EralpB