# TypeError in models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting this error:

user = models.OneToOneField(User)
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    # creating relationship
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # additional attributes
    portfolio = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, you need to specify what should happen, given the object to which you refer is removed, by the [**`on_delete=`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete). For example:

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    # creating relationship
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # additional attributes
    portfolio = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

The options here are:

> **`CASCADE`**
>
> Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint
>   `ON DELETE CASCADE` and also deletes the object containing the
>   `ForeignKey`.
>
> `Model.delete()` isn't called on related models, but the `pre_delete`
>   and `post_delete` signals are sent for all deleted objects.
>
> **`PROTECT`**
>
> Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising `ProtectedError`,
>   a subclass of `django.db.IntegrityError`.
>
> **`SET_NULL`**
>
> Set the `ForeignKey` null; this is only possible if `null` is `True`.
>
> **`SET_DEFAULT`**
>
> Set the `ForeignKey` to its `default` value; a default for the
>   `ForeignKey` must be set.
>
> **`SET()`**
>
> Set the `ForeignKey` to the value passed to `SET()`, or if a callable
>   is passed in, the result of calling it. In most cases, passing a
>   callable will be necessary to avoid executing queries at the time your
>   `models.py` is imported (...)
>
> **`DO_NOTHING`**
>
> Take no action. If your database backend enforces referential
>   integrity, this will cause an `IntegrityError` unless you manually add
>   an `SQL ON DELETE` constraint to the database field.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question is answered here [Getting TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' when trying to add parent table after child table with entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026548/getting-typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-on-delete)

Basically following should fix url problem

From Django 2.0 on_delete is required:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

put 'on_delete = models.CASCADE' in the constructor

what it does: when you will delete the user object as you have referenced it in the user field of your model. it will also delete the model object of UserProfileInfo for taht particular user.