# Django Models setup

Tags: python-3.x, django, powershell

I'm  getting a typeerror:
`__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'`

```
class Topic(models.Model)    
    text=models.CharField(max_length=200)   
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='entries'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on\_delete' when trying to add parent table after child table with entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026548/getting-typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-on-delete)

Answer (score 1):

add the `on_delete=models.CASCADE` in your topic of ForeignKey, like this:

```
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in Django when you us ForeignKey need to add on_delete=models.CASCADE it mean when you delete Topic, in Entry model topic is same will be delete together