# sync_to_async problem with scrapy-django-dashboard

Tags: python, django, scrapy

i want to use scrapy and django for scrape some date and i implemented it with scrapy-django-dashboard document well but when i run this commant:

scrapy crawl post_spider -a id=1 -a do_action=yes

i get this error:

django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context -
use a thread or sync_to_async.

this is my model.py class in django :

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class NewsWebsite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    scraper = models.ForeignKey(
        Scraper, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    scraper_runtime = models.ForeignKey(
        SchedulerRuntime, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44026807
    news_website = models.ForeignKey(
        NewsWebsite, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    checker_runtime = models.ForeignKey(
        SchedulerRuntime, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ArticleItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Article


@receiver(pre_delete)
def pre_delete_handler(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(instance, NewsWebsite):
        if instance.scraper_runtime:
            instance.scraper_runtime.delete()

    if isinstance(instance, Article):
        if instance.checker_runtime:
            instance.checker_runtime.delete()


pre_delete.connect(pre_delete_handler)
```

and this is my spider:

```
class ArticleSpider(DjangoSpider):

    name = 'article_spider'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._set_ref_object(NewsWebsite, **kwargs)
        self.scraper = self.ref_object.scraper
        self.scrape_url = self.ref_object.url
        self.scheduler_runtime = self.ref_object.scraper_runtime
        self.scraped_obj_class = Article
        self.scraped_obj_item_class = ArticleItem
        super(ArticleSpider, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

also this is my pipline:

```
class DjangoWriterPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if spider.conf['DO_ACTION']:
            try:
                item['news_website'] = spider.ref_object

                checker_rt = SchedulerRuntime(runtime_type='C')
                checker_rt.save()
                item['checker_runtime'] = checker_rt

                item.save()
                spider.action_successful = True
                spider.logger.info("{cs}Item {id} saved to Django DB.{ce}".format(
                    id=item._id_str,
                    cs=spider.bcolors['OK'],
                    ce=spider.bcolors['ENDC']))

            except IntegrityError as e:
                spider.logger.error(str(e))
                raise DropItem("Missing attribute.")

        return item
```

as you can see i implemented it just like document but when i want to run scrapy command i have sync_to_async error .
even i put  @sync_to_async on top of   def process_item(self, item, spider): function but it still doesnt work

my database is postgis

this is the link of document:
https://scrapy-django-dashboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

more about the error :

```
[2022-01-10 15:29:21,617] engine: INFO - Closing spider (finished)
2022-01-10 15:29:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[2022-01-10 15:29:21,619] log: INFO - Closing Django DB connection.
2022-01-10 15:29:21 [post_spider] INFO: Closing Django DB connection.
[2022-01-10 15:29:21,623] signal: ERROR - Error caught on signal handler: <bound method DjangoBaseSpider.spider_closed of <PostSpider 'post_spider' at 0x7f4bd8148fa0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mehdi/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 161, in maybeDeferred_coro
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/mehdi/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/home/mehdi/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy_django_dashboard/spiders/django_base_spider.py", line 299, in spider_closed
    connection.close()
  File "/home/mehdi/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Comment: 1) Where exactly exception occurs? Stack trance 2) Take note, that scrapy is run on twisted and thus async by it nature, and django started to implement async practices not so long ago.

Comment: i got this error after running this command: scrapy crawl post_spider -a id=1 -a do_action=yes   after that  i did put this decorator  @sync_to_async  top of   def process_item(self, item, spider) in pipeline because   i had this error before and i did this my problem was solved . in this time thats not  working

Comment: It is in django_base_spider.py", line 299 - you should add this code to question. Although my guess is you trying to wrap scrapy call to django's sync_to_async

Comment: this line (299) just says  the connection is close because of another reason :         self.log("Closing Django DB connection.", logging.INFO)
        connection.close()     infact the problem in about sync_to_async